# backbone.js: how to bind render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The following code works but I would like to improve readability and accessibility avoiding to write `callbacks`.

I need to render my view when fetch is performed on my collection.

Here the working code:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extends({

    initialize: function()
    {
        var that = this;

        MyCollection.fetch({
            success: function () {
                that.render();
            }
        });
    },

    ....

});
```

Here my attempt which does not work:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extends({
    initialize: function()
    {
        MyCollection.fetch();
        MyCollection.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    ....
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the `context` for the call to `bind`. Like this:

```
MyCollection.bind('change', this.render, this);
```

One excellent thing about Coffeescript is that it takes care of these things much more cleanly.

ETA: the `change` event isn’t triggered on `fetch`, it’s only triggered when one of the models in the collection changes. [`reset` is](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch), though. Also, you’re binding to the event after triggering the fetch, not sure if that’s what you intend.

Aside: seems confusing to me that you’re capitalising the `MyCollection` member, makes it easily mixed up with a `class`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me capitalising error. Anyway `MyCollection.bind('change', this.render, this);` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer with a possible solution. But can you give more of an explanation of what’s happening? Does it just never render?

Comment: Making `MyCollection.bind('change', this.render, this);` The render is never call. About the model..shold it change when the collection fetch is performed? if yes, how can I make it?

Comment: Why don’t you bind to both the `reset` and `change` events? You can just put `'change reset'` in the call to `bind`.

Comment: make sure to bind your events on your collection before you fetch.

        MyCollection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
        MyCollection.fetch();

rather than

        MyCollection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
        MyCollection.fetch();

otherwise, in high latency environments (read: non-local development) you will not get an event.